# How to form validate joint drop down menu in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

HTML:

```
<form name="loginForm" ng-submit="submit()" novalidate>
    <select name="Month" ng-required="true" ng-model="dob.Month">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
    </select>

    <select name="Year" ng-required="true" ng-model="dob.Year">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

I want the error message to be (Month, Year needs to be selected!)

There is something like:

```
<span ng-if="loginForm.Year.$error.required">This is required!</span>
<span ng-if="loginForm.Month.$error.required">This is required!</span>
```

but I want the error message to (Month, Year needs to be selected!)

Is there a way of creating forloop for these select menus and looking if they are $invalid - required?

Answer (score 0):

You could put validation on form itself

```
<span ng-if="loginForm.$invalid">Month, Year needs to be selected!</span>
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/UATU3JhlhEumk3pkLTy3?p=preview)

Comment: It does work but i wanted if Year is selected - I want error message to be (Month needs to be selected) and same for other way round (Year needs to be selected) or both (Year and Month needs to be selected).

Answer (score 0):

If you want the same error message to be displayed if either the month or year are invalid, you can combine your two error messages above into a single message, like this:

```
<span ng-if="loginForm.Year.$error.required || loginForm.Month.$error.required">
     Month and Year need to be selected!
</span>
```

This will display the error message if both are unselected, or if one is selected and the other is not.

---

**EDIT:**

To achieve the desired behavior, you should have three separate error messages with different ng-if conditions, like this:

```
<p>
  <span ng-if="selectsForm.month.$error.required && selectsForm.year.$error.required">Month and year must be selected!</span>
  <span ng-if="selectsForm.$dirty && (selectsForm.month.$error.required || !selectsForm.year.$error)">Month needs to be selected!</span>
  <span ng-if="selectsForm.$dirty && (selectsForm.year.$error.required || !selectsForm.month.$error)">Year needs to be selected!</span>
</p>
```

Comment: I have put a comment on Pankaj Parkar - the way i wanted